# Reporte entre 2 fechas en Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

Disculpen; me sale este error al exportar a Excel. ¿Me podrían decir por qué sería el error?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En esta parte les pongo la función que hice para exportar a Excel:

```
public function imprimir_excel($FInicial, $FFinal){

    //cargando la libreria
    $this->load->library('PHPExcel');

    // Propiedades del archivo excel

    // hacemos que queda activa la primera hoja al abrir el excel
    $this->phpexcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);

    // Hoja de excel para trabajar con PHP

    $sheet = $this->phpexcel->getActiveSheet();

    //aplicamos dimensiones a las celdas dependiendo del contenido
    $sheet->getColumnDimension('A')->setWidth(6);
    $sheet->getColumnDimension('C')->setWidth(12);
    $sheet->getColumnDimension('B')->setWidth(25);
    $sheet->getColumnDimension('D')->setWidth(14);
    $sheet->getColumnDimension('E')->setWidth(12);

    //Excribimos el titulo de las columnas de nuestro reporte
    $sheet->setCellValue('A1', 'NUM.');
    $sheet->setCellValue('B1', 'NOMBRE');
    $sheet->setCellValue('C1', 'Distrito');
    $sheet->setCellValue('D1', 'fecha');
    $sheet->setCellValue('E1', 'Observacion');

    //consultamos nuestros reportes del registros  especifico
    $reportes=$this->model_reportes->reportesGenera($FInicial, $FFinal);

    $i=1;
    if (isset($reportes)) {

        foreach ($reportes as $fila):

            $idregistro=$fila->idregistro;
            $long=strlen($idregistro);
            $generar=str_repeat('0',4-$long);
            // $id_generado=$generar.$idregistro;

            ++$i;

            //una vez que tenemos los valores escribimos en nuestro archivo de excel
            // $sheet->setCellValue('A'.$i, $id_generado);
            $sheet->setCellValue('B'.$i, $fila->nombre_establecimiento);
            $sheet->setCellValue('C'.$i, $fila->distrito);
            $sheet->setCellValue('D'.$i, $fila->fecha);
            $sheet->setCellValue('E'.$i, $fila->observacion);

            //aplicamos un estilo a nuestra celdas de contenido
            // $this->phpexcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A'.$i.':I'.$i)->applyFromArray($filas_formato);
        endforeach;
    }
    //aplicamos un estilo

    //$this->phpexcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A1:I1')->applyFromArray($titulo_formato);

    // Preparando para generar archivo de excel
    header("Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel");
    $nombreArchivo = date('Y-m-d');
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$nombreArchivo.xls\"");
    header("Cache-Control: max-age=0");

    // Genera Excel
    $writer = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($this->phpexcel, "Excel5");

    // descarga el archivo de Excel
    $writer->save('php://output');
    exit;

}
```

Comment: Puedes hacer un `var_dump` de la variable `$reportes` ?

Answer (score 1):

Cambia tu nombre de archivo por eso y modifica el header, capaz solucione tu problema:

```
$nombreArchivo = 'sample_' . time() . '.xls'; 
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="' . $nombreArchivo . '"');
```

Comment: En tu caso agregale el charset nomas

Comment: sigue lo mismo :(

Answer (score 0):

Revisando tu código puedo ver dos cosas:

- `$i=1;`//debería ser `$i=2;` dado que esta línea sería la cabecera y ya la asignaste anteriormente. Algo funcional
- Me parece que igual deberías asignarle un nombre al momento de guardar. `$writer->save($nombreArchivo.'.xls');` //Algo técnico

Prueba estas cosas y escribe tus comentarios

Comment: ¿Te funcionó esta respuesta? Comenta un poco más tu error o intentos

Answer (score 0):

Al principio: `header("Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8");`

Headers finales:

```
header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="nombreFichero.xlsx"');
header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');
```

Visto en: [PHPExcel Celdas Con utf8](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/51291/phpexcel-celdas-con-utf8)

Answer (score 0):

Esta es la solucion. Corresponde a dar un nombre correcto y quitar la fecha.

```
header("Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel");
$nombreArchivo = "Nombre";
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$nombreArchivo.xls\"");
header("Cache-Control: max-age=0");
```

Comment: Aclaraciones sobre la pregunta se deben realizar como comentarios, revisar  [answer].