# PHPExcel Celdas Con utf8

Tags: php, excel

tengo el problema que no me reconoce los caracteres especiales, he intentado con lo siguiente pero no me funciona:

Poniendolo En UTF8 =

```
 $titulosColumnas = array('Código', 'Inclusión de la Noticia DD/MM/AAAA', 'Fecha de la Noticia  DD/MM/AAAA', 'Nombre del Medio', 'Sección', 'Página Web', 
                                'Título de la Noticia', 'Fuente de Información', 'Resumen Noticia', 'Tipo de Delito', 'Estado Procesal', 'Delitos Relacionados',
                                'País', 'Departamento', 'Ciudad', 'Tipo Persona', 'Primer Nombre', 'Segúndo Nombre', 'Primer Apellido ó Razón Social', 'Segundo Apellido', 'Alias', 'Edad', 'Caracteristicas', 'Número Documento', 'Tipo Documento', 'Lugar Expedición', 'Dirección', 'Noticia Completa', 'Imagen');


            // Se agregan los titulos del reporte
        $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)
                ->setCellValue('A1',   utf8_encode($titulosCol

umnas[0]))
                    ->setCellValue('B1',   utf8_encode($titulosColumnas[1]))
                    ->setCellValue('C2',   utf8_encode($titulosColumnas[2]))
                    ->setCellValue('D1',   utf8_encode($titulosColumnas[3]))
                    ->setCellValue('E1',   utf8_encode($titulosColumnas[4]))
                    ->setCellValue('F1',   utf8_encode($titulosColumnas[5]))
                    ->setCellValue('G1',   utf8_encode($titulosColumnas[6]))
                    ->setCellValue('H1',   utf8_encode($titulosColumnas[7]))
                    ->setCellValue('I1',   utf8_encode($titulosColumnas[8]))
                    ->setCellValue('J1',   utf8_encode($titulosColumnas[9]))
                    ->setCellValue('K1',   utf8_encode($titulosColumnas[10]))
                    ->setCellValue('L1',   utf8_encode($titulosColumnas[11]))
                    ->setCellValue('M1',   utf8_encode($titulosColumnas[12]))
                    ->setCellValue('N1',   utf8_encode($titulosColumnas[13]))
                    ->setCellValue('O1',   utf8_encode($titulosColumnas[14]))
                    ->setCellValue('P1',   utf8_encode($titulosColumnas[15]))
                    ->setCellValue('Q1',   utf8_encode($titulosColumnas[16]))
                    ->setCellValue('R1',   utf8_encode($titulosColumnas[17]))
                    ->setCellValue('S1',   utf8_encode($titulosColumnas[18]))
                    ->setCellValue('T1',   utf8_encode($titulosColumnas[19]))
                    ->setCellValue('U1',   utf8_encode($titulosColumnas[20]))
                    ->setCellValue('V1',   utf8_encode($titulosColumnas[21]))
                    ->setCellValue('W1',   utf8_encode($titulosColumnas[22]))
                    ->setCellValue('X1',   utf8_encode($titulosColumnas[23]))
                    ->setCellValue('Y1',   utf8_encode($titulosColumnas[24]))
                    ->setCellValue('Z1',   utf8_encode($titulosColumnas[25]))
                    ->setCellValue('AA1',  utf8_encode($titulosColumnas[26]))
                    ->setCellValue('AB1',  utf8_encode($titulosColumnas[27]))
                    ->setCellValue('AC1',  utf8_encode($titulosColumnas[28]));
```

añadiendo el utf-8 a los headers

```
  header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet; charset=utf-8');
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="Resumen_20170223.xlsx"; charset=utf-8' );
        header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');
```

Pero nada funciona alguien sabe como solucionarlo?

Comment: pega bien el codigo, parece que falta parte

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Prueba a poner al principio `header("Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8");`

Después tu código pero quita todos los `utf8_encode()`

Y los header finales:

```
header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="nombreFichero.xlsx"');
header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');
```

El problema parece que viene por traducir los caracteres a utf8 cuando tu documento ya es utf8.

Comment: Muchas gracias era eso

Answer (score 1):

Si usas sublime text codifica tu archivo php en utf8 de la siguiente manera:

`File > Save With Encoding > UTF-8`

Elimina la función `utf8_encode` y corrige los errores con las tildes y ñ

También podrías optimizar tu código de la siguiente manera:

```
$titulosColumnas = array(
    'Código', 
    'Inclusión de la Noticia DD/MM/AAAA', 
    'Fecha de la Noticia  DD/MM/AAAA', 
    ...
);

$fila = 1;
$columna = 0;

foreach($titulosColumnas as $value) {
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()
                ->setCellValueByColumnAndRow($columna, $fila, $value);
    $columna++;//Incrementas el valor de la columna
}
```

Y lo exportas como lo menciona **nachfren**